# MultiTrigger with the some extra condition on load

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatrigger, wpf-style

I have a tool window in my application. there are some text input available and i have some validation rule on those text boxes.
say, 
validation rule 1
Validation rule 2 
validation rule 3

I have a button on that tool window and a style like the bellow

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=HeightTextbox, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=WeightTextBox, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=HeartRateTextBox, Path=(Validation.HasError)}"     Value="false"      />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

and the ok button

```
<Button Content="Ok" x:Name="OkButton" Height="32" Width="80" Command="{Binding OkCommand}"/>
```

It is working fine but I want the button to be disabled every time user opens no matters where it is satisfying validation rule or not but the rule should be applied too.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then you could use the `CanExecute` on your `Command` to determine the `IsEnabled` property. HTH

Comment: how do you hide your tool window? I mean by closing or just hiding (using `Hide()` method)? Of course if using `Close()` method, you need to reload the window to open it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding some `DataTrigger` listening to `Visibility` property using `OneTime` mode binding and set the `IsEnabled` to `false`. This trigger should be placed after your multitrigger so that it can override that trigger:

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <!-- your multi trigger ... -->

   <DataTrigger Property="{Binding Visibility,
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                           Mode=OneTime}" Value="Visible">
       <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
   </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

The above works only when you hide your tool window by calling `Close()` method, so next time when open the window, it will be loaded first.

If you use something like `Hide()` method to hide the tool window and open it again using `Show()`, you can try using the following code instead:

```
<sys:Boolean x:Key="f">false</sys:Boolean>
<Style.Triggers>
   <!-- your multi trigger ... -->

   <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
       <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Resources[f],
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel},
                 Mode=OneTime}"/>
   </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Note about the prefix `sys` used here, you have to import the namespace `System` into the XAML code. I hope you know how to do this.